# Using widget in a tab of ttk.Notebook?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to display a simple Notebook widget with two tabs. Here's the code of what I tried without all the unnecessary code in between:

```cs
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

color_bg = "gray20"
font = "Lucida Sans Typewriter"
DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 16

class Tab(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack()

        self.textfield = tk.Text(
            self.parent, 
            font = (font, DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE), 
            background = color_bg, 
            bd = 10, 
            relief = tk.FLAT)

        self.textfield.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)


class TabDisplay(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

        self.tabholder = ttk.Notebook(parent)
        self.tabholder.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True, side = tk.TOP)

        self.viewtab = Tab(self.tabholder)
        self.edittab = Tab(self.tabholder)
        self.tabholder.add(self.viewtab, text = "View")
        self.tabholder.add(self.edittab, text = "Edit")


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # Set size and position
        self.x_pos = 0
        self.y_pos = 0
        self.width = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.height = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        self.parent.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}+{self.x_pos}+{self.y_pos}")
        self.parent.resizable = True

        # Add Widgets
        self.tabdisplay = TabDisplay(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
    root.mainloop()
```

When I run this, it does not display an actual notebook. It just displays the two tabs below eachother. However, when I replace `Tab(self.tabholder)` with `tk.Frame(self.tabholder)` it functions perfectly (apart from not using the contents of the `Tab()` class).

Why does it not display correctly with my `Tab()` class? I have never had issues with classes that inherit from `tk.Frame` until I started using `ttk.Notebook()`. Is it an issue with ttk?

EDIT: I have since found out that the actual culprit is the Text widget within the `Tab()` class. Now my question is why does adding a widget break the notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a frame like a box. You create a box, and then you put widgets inside the box. Only, in your case you're creating widgets in the box but placing them outside the box when you add them to `self.parent` rather than `self`.

When you create a class that inherits from `tk.Frame`, every widget inside that class should be a direct child or descendant of `self`. In doing so, an instance of the class becomes a self-contained object that can be the child of any other widget.

For example:

```
class Tab(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.textfield = tk.Text(
            self, 
            ...
```

... and:

```
class TabDisplay(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.tabholder = ttk.Notebook(self)
        ...
```